# How to integrate Enthought.canopy and Continuum.anaconda in one python env

Tags: python, anaconda, canopy

I have anaconda installed on my computer(windows 10 64bit py2.7) and now want to use modules in the canopy (mayavi or vtk).
Is it possible to integrate these two kits ?

Comment: hmhm, have you tried `conda install mayavi`?

Comment: wow ,that works. many thanks! I've tried using pycharm where the installing is conducted by pip and it failed,but forgotten the powerful conda!